# Calculate days until Christmas

Tags: delphi, date

I need to calculate the number of days until the next Christmas day, 24.12.
I wonder if there is a function to calculate very simple the next Christmas day.

```
     deltaDays := Today - NextChristmas;
```

Comment: Christmas day is the 25th of December. 24 is Christmas eve.

Comment: it's 35 days from now. What is the question?

Answer (score 10):

You can use the `DaysBetween` function in `DateUtils`:

```
var
  Christmas: TDate;
begin

  Christmas := EncodeDate(YearOf(Now), 12, 24);
  ShowMessageFmt('Days to Christmas: %d', [DaysBetween(Now, Christmas)]);
```

Of course, special logic is required to handle the days after Christmas but before the new year.

Comment: can I use the function :   function CompareDate(const ADate, BDate: TDateTime) : TValueRelationship :  to make this special logic code very compact?  I do not see a good approach for a very simple code

Answer (score 8):

If you use this a lot in your code, better to create a function to do it, like this:

```
function DaysToNextChristmas(Date: TDateTime): Cardinal;
var
  Year, Month, Day: Word;
  Christmas: TDateTime;
begin
  Date := Int(Date);
  DecodeDate(Date, Year, Month, Day);
  if (Month = 12) and (Day >= 25) then Inc(Year);
  Christmas := EncodeDate(Year, 12, 25);
  Result := Trunc(Christmas - Date);
end;
```

Explanation:

- As we should already know, Delphi's `TDateTime` data type is actually a `Double` (floating-point). The integer part represents the date, and the fraction represents the time. That's why I use `Int` on the beginning of the function, to get the integer (date) part. Actually, it has no use, so you could simply remove it.
- To know when the next christmas happens, we need the year of the reference date, we could use `YearOf` from `DateUtils` unit. But because we have to check wether or not the reference date is between christmas and new year, here we use `DecodeDate` to also get the month and day value.
- Check if the month is 12 (December) and the day is 25 or larger, if the answer is yes then increase the year value, the next christmas must be on the next year.
- Build the next christmas date using `EncodeDate`.
- Use the substraction operator (-) to get the days count from the reference date (argument) to the next christmas. Assign it to the `Result` variable to return it.

Usage example:

```
ShowMessageFmt('Days to Christmas: %d', [DaysToNextChristmas(Now)]);
```

I hope it helps.